# Tool helping split a huge class into two

Tags: python, refactoring, developer-tools

Is there a good aid/tool for helping me split a huge class into parts?
The code does its job well, but having a class over 500 lines is not comfortable. I am sure it could be split up into smaller pieces.

This time I am interested in a tool for python, but I am sure it does not count.

Comment: which programming language/environment are you using?

Comment: I hope it exists. You can draw a graph between methods and fields (method M uses field F). Based on this graph, an algorithm can suggest.

Comment: I am currently using py3k, but I think the graph could be created language-independent.

Answer (score 6):

Why can't you do this manually? 500 lines is not that much to deal with. I doubt any tool will be able to split up a class meaningfully in the context of the purpose it serves. I suggest you split it up on your own and redesign/refactor the code while you're at it.

Comment: I added my comment to the question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is it about the 500 lines of code that makes you "not comfortable"? Why do you think you need to only split the class into two new classes? Perhaps the class is fine as it is (500 isn't huge), or, perhaps the class needs to be split into 3 or 4 different classes.

Without more information, I'd say that a tool isn't going to help you until you can understand why you feel the need to split it into smaller pieces. No tool will tell you *how* to split the class.

Ask yourself what the single responsibility of the class is. If you come up with more than one, then the class should be split at least along the lines of responsibility. If you come up with 6, you have a fair amount of work to do.

Comment: Yes, right, no tool will tell you _how_ to split it, but based on my comment to the question, it can give you really good hints.

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool (outside of academia) that will give you the hints you need. Even if it did, the tool is not going to help you design a better set of classes, because that requires knowledge that an automated tool simply does not have (you'd be approaching AI).

So, I'd encourage you to stop looking for a tool and start looking at and thinking about the design of your code, and the responsibilities that each class should have.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it counts what language you mean. You can do much safer automated refactoring for languages like java compared to languages like python (because of dynamic nature of python).

In Python it is normal (*"pythonic"*) to use `getattr()` while in java using introspection is more like *"don't use it unless you have to"*. Such techniques  makes it almost impossible to for automated refactoring tools to work because they are not able to detect all relations.

Anyhow, for both java and python I use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) for refactoring. It does the job quite well. For python, you will need [pydev](http://pydev.org/) plugin or aptana studio.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, that refactoring is more difficult in python, than in java, but I personally do not use `getattr()` on a daily basis, so I am fine if it misses those connections.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [ExtC Visualizer](http://code.google.com/p/ext-c/), which is for java, and can't get it working yet.